# No DbContext was found in assembly 'project.api'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a .net core project which have multiple projects

```
project.api
project.data
```

my DbContext file is in `project.data -> Context`

when I am running. `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -o ../project.data`
I keep get the following error
No DbContext was found in assembly 'project.api'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

I have tried to add -c

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -o ../project.data --context ../project.data.Context.DatabaseContext
```

I get the DbContext can't be found at `project.data.Context.DatabaseContext`

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I add the DbContext in program.cs after

```
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

which suppose to be before and I used the following command from the api directory

```
dotnet ef migrations add IntialCreate -p ../project-data/project-data.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to run from the folder containing the API project, try specifying [target project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options):

> `--project <PROJECT>` `-p`    Relative path to the project folder of the target project. Default value is the current folder.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -p ../project.data
```

Comment: Guru Stron I did and now I get this error Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Comment: Also I tried to use --msbuildprojectextensionspath I get Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @AliMardini can you please post a full [mre] somehwere?

Comment: @AliMardini Also be sure that you use folder where .csproj of data project is located.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution.

First: if the project you're creating the migration in is not the project in which the dbcontext is defined, you need to specify it when adding your dbcontext to the services. For example:

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
         ...

      ServerVersion.AutoDetect(dbOptions.Value.BusinessConnectionString), 
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly"));

        ...
    });
```

Second: If the solution above didn't work, Make sure you've installed **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** In the project in which you're running the migration.

Third: If you still have this problem, then, open the package manager console,
in VS, select the appropriate project, and run this command: **Add-Migration init** This command will either create your migration or tell you what's wrong with your project.